# How do I frame my basement wall to loose the minimum amount of space?

Tags: basement, framing

The drywall in the stairs going into my basement align flush with the concrete foundation. I need to frame this wall which will also be where the TV hangs from. Using 2x4s setting a couple inches off the foundation and insulation will protrude into the doorway opening going to the basement so I'm trying to find the best way to minimize how much space this wall will extend into the doorway. One thought it using 2x3s instead and put them closer to the wall and switch to foam insulation instead of fiberglass. I was also going to use slim boxes and take the wires up vertically instead of through the 2x3s and double up the 2x3s where the tv would hang. Anyone see any issues with this setup or have another alternative?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format.

Comment: Excavate outside to footing. Apply XPS or other suitable insulation. Refill and regrade. Plaster or parge or tile the concrete inside. Lose almost no space inside.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a structural wall that needs to hold up weight, just to screw drywall on.

A 1/2 hole though the studs for a cable, should not hurt.

Single 2x3 should also hold a tv, unless rotten.

Only problem is that 2x3s might be warp more than 2x4s, so selection more important.

Metal studs might be another idea, they are straight, but don't know their sizes

Comment: I highly recommend not using metal studs for this type of project if you don't have experience with them. That's based on personal experience (mounting stuff on walls in commercial buildings that had metal studs, so no choice there) and many posts on DIY. Metal studs *can* be quite effective, but there is a learning curve.

Comment: If the location of the tv is known, possible to add 2x3s or even a piece of plywood at the location.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've thought about using metal studs but have 0% experience with them so I'm leaning more towards wood. 

Another thought I had was to taper the width of the wall from where the drywall by the steps would attach to a 1x3 furring strip and gradually go out the width of normal 2x4s over something like 4 or 6 feet. I have a table saw and can use math to figure the angle of the wall at the 16" vertical intervals so the drywall will sit flush along the way until it joins the normal parallel to the foundation 2x4s. Anyone ever seen or done something like that?

Comment: It is more work to do right, and an oopsie might not be notice till latter.  If you think you do it, would go for it.